# Ckeditor: show and hide inline toolbar on demand

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, inline

I use inline `Ckeditor` to edit content. By default, the inline editor is activated by double click a `div` with `contenteditable="true"`. I want to activate this inline editor when I click a button, and hide it when I click another button.
Here is an example of html code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
   <div id="first" contenteditable="true">first</div>
   <div id="second" contenteditable="true">second</div>

   <input type="button" value="show inline editor">
   <input type="button" value="hide inline editor">
 </body>
</html>
```

Jsfiddle shows the default behavior and what i want to have http://jsfiddle.net/vdRYL/

Comment: It will be easy for us to solve this issue if you could create a jsfiddle(jsfiddle.net) showing the default behaviour of Ckeditor.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and for editing. Here is the jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/vdRYL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CKeditor seems to be activating the editor-window on `focus` of `contenteditable` element and not on `double-click`.
You can do something like this to get your buttons to work,

http://jsfiddle.net/nagendra_rao/vdRYL/1/

Answer (score 2):

We can hide and show toolbar. I have achieved this functionality using following way:

Open `ckeditor.js` file. And paste below code at the end of the file

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
   CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (ev) {  
      document.getElementById(ev.editor.id + '_top').style.display = 'none';  


      ev.editor.on('focus', function (e) {  
         document.getElementById(ev.editor.id + '_top').style.display = 'block';  

      });  
      ev.editor.on('blur', function (e) {  
         document.getElementById(ev.editor.id + '_top').style.display = 'none';  

      });  
   });  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `focusManager.blur(true)` in order to hide the toolbar.

http://jsfiddle.net/vdRYL/24/

```
var cke = CKEDITOR.inline('target');

var btnClose = document.getElementById('btnClose');
btnClose.addEventListener('click', function(event){
cke.focusManager.blur(true);
});
```

More info on focusManager here: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.focusManager-method-blur

Answer (score 1):

### For Angular

The toolbar element has class "**ck-editor__top**", so i used below code to hide / display it:

**component.html**

added to 'ckeditor' tag below 3 listeners:

```
<ckeditor
        (ready)="changeEditorToolbar('none')"
        (focus)="changeEditorToolbar('block')"
        (blur)="changeEditorToolbar('none')"
>
</ckeditor>
```

**component.ts**

```
changeEditorToolbar(displayValue)
{
    let elements =  Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('ck-editor__top') as HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement>);
    elements[0].style.display = displayValue;
}
```

Note:
*Pay attention, if you have multiple ck editors in the same component, you should not use [0] to get the first one*

Comment: Worked great in my angular code! Thank you! :D